# How to show a UIButton of UITableView's Section Header above UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I am using UIKit SDK for building the app. I have added a button as a UITableView header for section. I want it to stick to the top of UINavigationBar while scrolling. It does stick to the top but the button goes beneath the navigation bar. I want the button to be visible above the navigation bar. I tried setting the `layer.zPosition` value of navigation bar to `-1` but it hides the entire navigation bar.

Here's my code for the button and the tableview section header:

```swift
lazy var playButton: UIButton = {
        let pButton = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        pButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: GlobalConstants.darkGreenColor)!
        pButton.tintColor = .white
        pButton.setImage(playIcon, for: .normal)
        pButton.layer.cornerRadius = 40
        pButton.enableAutoLayout()
        pButton.clipsToBounds = false
        return pButton
    }()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
let headerView = UIView()
headerView.backgroundColor = .clear
headerView.addSubview(playButton)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
playButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
playButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
playButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
playButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor)
])
return headerView
}
```

How do I solve this ?

[image: screenshot of app]

Comment: its not an header you should use large title attributes to achieve some thing like this

Comment: But it is for showing textual title right ?

Comment: yes but I think you could find something with same as large title attribute right bar button kinda thing

Comment: right bar button is fine. but I want the button to stick on to tableview while not scrolling and stick on to navigationbar while scrolling. You can see such beahvior in spotify app for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your button further up in the view hierarchy, probably in the window directly:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.addSubview(floatingButton)
```

Then in your viewController override scrollViewDidScroll and set the y position of your floatingButton

Comment: I instead added the button as subview to UINavigationBar and it is working

Comment: Touch is working too?